# React-Native/Rails/OAuth Sign In Flow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, react-native, jwt

I am currently in the process of integrating a React Native android app to complete sign in through my Rails API server backend using OAuth2. The current architecture works as follows:

```
-visit /request_token on the rails server
 -redirect to Facebook for Sign In
 -facebook redirects to /access_token on the rails server
-Rails server completes authentication, pulling the user data, and generating a JWT
-JWT is used for all local API requests made to the rails server
```

The goal is to have the React Native app start this process, so it ultimately ends up with the JWT which can be used to pull data from the Rails server. Facebook OAuth is only used as an intermediary to generate these JWT's (and because OAuth is a requirement of the project).

Does anyone have any insight on the best way to go about setting up this relationship? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Currently exploring starting the process from Mobile instead of from the server, and passing the code to the `/access_token` endpoint, thus skipping  the `/request_token` endpoint all together.

This seems like an easier solution to starting the sign in, but im not sure how to get the code I actually want. Access Token has tons of examples, but very few exist for the Code used to generate Access Tokens.

I'll update when I know more.

Comment: Have you looked in to something like Auth0? I'm currently using it for a React (web) + Rails-API project. 

A gem - `knock` - on the rails side deals with the token provided by Auth0.

Comment: I have not. Looking over the website, Auth0 looks to be very robust. I would love to hear more about your process using it :)

Comment: Sure email me at pgord1 at gmail dot com